# Eager loading in deep level nested association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model

I have models having nested associations. I want to load all nested records from just one query.

`hotel has_many rooms`

`rooms has_many room_variants`

`room_variant has_many seasonal_rates`

I search for hotel with hotel name, and want to load nested model data.

For one level nesting we can do `Hotel.search('test').includes(:rooms)`. I am not finding a way to load deep level nested association model entries.

Answer (score 46):

You can do:

```
Hotel.search('test').includes(rooms: { room_variants: :seasonal_rates })
```

See the "Nested Association Hash" section of [Eager Loading Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) in the RailsGuides.

Comment: I can't mark this as the answer even though it is, but +1. Thanks